# Bundle images with binary using wxWidgets on Linux

Tags: linux, wxwidgets

I have a small wxWidget application that uses image files at several places. I plan to deploy this application soon and was wondering if anyone could recommend me a way to bundle all resource files on Linux ?

Is there maybe even a way I could put them into the binary somehow ?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XPM](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxbitmapoverview.html)